# image hiding in my xcode project

Tags: iphone, image, resources

I finally finished my app which i'm excited about. One last thing that bugs me is that when i run my app, the first photo shown is not the image i want. I go to delete this image but it's nowhere to be found (not in resources or outside on desktop) Is there a special folder where it retains and copy images to the project for safe keeping?

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean by "the first photo shown"? Are you referring to the image that displays as part of the launching process? If so, that is the Default.png file, and is referenced in your application's info.plist.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few things to try:

- Do a clean build. Clean all targets.
- If this is on the device, tap and hold the icon in the home screen until all of the icons start to do the wiggle dance and then tap the 'X' to remove your app from the device. Re-run the app from Xcode.
- Do the same as the previous suggestion on the simulator if that is where you are seeing the problem.
- Look for any references to the file name within the code that may have been missed by doing a Edit | Find | Find in Project... in Xcode.
- Make sure the file didn't overwrite some known file such as Default.png on accident and so you're seeing the correct filename, but it was saved with the wrong image data.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Matt Long is correct.  A Clean Build may very well be your answer.  If you used to have a resource that you deleted, there is a good chance that that resource is still being included in your target, if you have NOT done a clean build.